# All functions with the property $ k \mid f(m+n) \iff k \mid f(m)+f(n)$

Tags: number-theory, functional-equations, divisibility

Let $\mathbb N$ be the set of all positive integers. How can one find all functions $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that
$$ k \mid f(m+n) \iff k \mid f(m)+f(n)$$
For all positive integers $k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $k,x,y$ be integers.  Note that if $k | x \Longleftrightarrow k | y$ occurs for all $k$, then $x = y$. (If $x \neq y$, you could find some number dividing one but not the other).  Therefore, you simply need to find all functions $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$.  It turns out that the only such equations are of the form $f(x) = a x$, for some constant $a$ (See [Cauchy's Functional Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation)).